# How to package sub-folder for gcloud ml?

Tags: python, package, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to upload **my** project to google cloud ml-engine for training. I have followed the "getting started" guide, replacing in relevant places with my own files.

I manage to train locally using

```
gcloud ml-engine local train --module-name="my-model.task" --package-path=my-model/ -- ./my_model/model_params_google.json
```

Yes, I have dashes in the module name :(. I also made a symbolic link `my_module -> my-module` so that I can use the name with underscore instead of dash. In any case, I don't think this is the problem, since the above command works well locally.

My folder structure doesn't follow the recommended one, since I had the project before thinking about ml-engine. It looks like this:

```
my-model/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── setup.py
    ├── task.py
    ├── model_params_google.json
    ├── src
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── data_handler.py
    │   ├── elastic_helpers.py
    │   ├── model.py
```

The problem is that the `src` folder is not packaged/uploaded with the code, so in the cloud, when I say `from .src.model import model_fn` in `task.py`, it fails.

The command I use for packaging is (in folder `my-model/../`):

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training my_model_$(date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") \
    --staging-bucket gs://model-data \
    --job-dir $OUTPUT_PATH \
    --module-name="my_model.task" \
    --package-path=my_model/ \
    --region=$REGION \
    --config config.yaml --runtime-version 1.8 \
    -- \
    tf_crnn/model_params_google.json --verbosity DEBUG
```

It packages `my-model.0.0.0.tar.gz` without the contents of `my-model/src`. I cannot figure out why. I'm using the example `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['tensorflow>=1.8']

setup(
    name='my_model',
    version='0.1',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    description='my first model'
)
```

So, the question is, why does `gcloud` not pack the `src` folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the setup.py in the directory above `my-model`.

You can check your results by invoking:

```
python setup.py sdist
```

Then un-taring the tarball in the `dist` directory. As is, you'll see that `task.py` is not included in the tarball.

By moving `setup.py` one directory higher and repeating, you'll see that `task.py` is included, as is everything in src.

Comment: it works, but I think that by "below" you actually mean "above" . So currently it is `my-model/setup.py` and in the new version they are in parallel: `my-model/../setup.py`.